# Fast USB switch to share keyboard and mouse (like KVM)

Tags: windows, mac, usb, keyboard, kvm-switch

I use a `DeLOCK USB 2.0 Sharing Switch 2 - 1` to share my keyboard and mouse between my iMac (which is running Windows 7 natively through Bootcamp) and my Mac Mini.

Switching from the iMac/Win7 to the Mac Mini works okay, I press the button, and after about two seconds the Mac receives the input from the keyboard.

In the other direction, the delay is remarkably higher. It seems that Windows 7 needs about 5-10 seconds (to recognize the keyboard or whatever) until it receives input from it. I have tried other products as well, this one is the fastest I got.

**Now, I'm just wondering, is there anything I can do to make this delay shorter? Or does anybody know of a product (KVM, USB switch or whatever) that does not have any delay in switching?**

I imagine the switch could implement its own USB functionality to keep the connection to the Windows side open while the keyboard input goes to the Mac. So Windows does not notice the keyboard being 'disconnected', which means the switching could take place instantly.

Comment: I have this same problem, different KVM. Looks like Windows 7 needs to poll the USB ports and cheap KVM won't answer correctly when using the other computer. No idea how to fix it, short of buying a DDM supporting KVM, but they're too expensive. * Edit: Google says connecting the KVM with PS2 adapters may work, it didn't for me.

Comment: Also, a quick Google reveals this is a legitimate question, bad job from the people closing it.

Comment: I just discovered Synergy. This is THE solution for my problem. It's very easy to use, much faster than the USB solution, leads to less cables on my desktop, and best of all, it's free.

Comment: Been using Synergy for years, but its buggy and clunky. Two mice are not so bad on your desk, but 2 keyboards no! A fast K switch is needed when one computer is on VPN and the other isn't and you don't want to mess with the routing tables. The answer to your question is USB Dynamic Device Mapping. A DDM KVM does exactly what your describe. Unfortunately somehow ConnectPro seems to have a monopoly on these so prices are ridiculous and so are the bulky sizes. +1 for smart question and +sad for the close cabal who  assume that questions have no answers just because they couldn't imagine one.